# Apache - typing without www on my domain does not work

Tags: apache, ubuntu

When i typed:
`example.com` , my site works, but when i typed `www.example.com` or `http://example.com` it does not work, it give me `This site can’t be reached`.

This is my Apache Configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAlias http://example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What seems to be the problem here? Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the **DNS** settings for your domain, that if you have access to this.

Namely, you should add new record **CNAME** with the value **www** for your domain.

Comment: Adding an A record is better because it doesn't have performance issues. Adding a CNAME record is easier to update, because it updates itself. Its upto the OP for choosing any one.